# How can I forward email I move to non-specific subfolders of a specific parent folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

The following code forwards email I move to *specific* subfolders of the 'Outsourced Accounting' folder.

I would like to forward email moved to *any* subfolder of 'OutsourcedAccounting' without having to update the code any time a new subfolder is added.

How can I make this work for any subfolder of OutsourcedAccounting as opposed to just those I specifically name in the code?

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents OutsourcedAccounting As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents Subfolder1 As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents subfolder2 As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents Subfolder3 As Outlook.Items
Private olItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set OutsourcedAccounting = GetNS(olApp).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Outsourced Accounting").Items
    Set Subfolder1 = GetNS(olApp).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Outsourced Accounting").Folders("Subfolder1").Items
    Set subfolder2 = GetNS(olApp).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Outsourced Accounting").Folders("subfolder2").Items
    Set Subfolder3 = GetNS(olApp).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Outsourced Accounting").Folders("Subfolder3").Items
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub OutsourcedAccounting_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    On Error GoTo err_Handler
    Set olItem = item.Forward
    olItem.Recipients.Add "forwardingemail@gmail.com"
    olItem.Save
    olItem.Send
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End Sub

Private Sub Subfolder1_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    On Error GoTo err_Handler
    Set olItem = item.Forward
    olItem.Recipients.Add "forwardingemail@gmail.com"
    olItem.Save
    olItem.Send
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End Sub

Private Sub subfolder2_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    On Error GoTo err_Handler
    Set olItem = item.Forward
    olItem.Recipients.Add "forwardingemail@gmail.com"
    olItem.Save
    olItem.Send
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End Sub

Private Sub Subfolder3_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    On Error GoTo err_Handler
    Set olItem = item.Forward
    olItem.Recipients.Add "forwardingemail@gmail.com"
    olItem.Save
    olItem.Send
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    GoTo lbl_Exit
End Sub

Function GetNS(ByRef app As Outlook.Application) As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set GetNS = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Try using the FolderChange Event. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/folders-folderchange-event-outlook

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run code when new email comes to any subfolder in a Shared Mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881358/run-code-when-new-email-comes-to-any-subfolder-in-a-shared-mailbox)