# Alert user when the user manually moves an email to an Archive folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook, directory

I have found myself accidentally moving email items to an Archive folder instead of the standard folder in MS Outlook.  For example, for an email address of Example@Email.Com, I open the Archive to locate an old email in folder "KeepThis" but then I forget to collapse the Archive folder and so I inadvertently move some other email message later on into the Archive/KeepThis folder when I really wanted to move it to the Example@Email.Com/KeepThis folder.

**Is there a way to use VBA code to alert the user when an email item is manually moved into an Archive folder?**

I tried unsuccessfully to modify the code by @thims at [create-outlook-rule-which-runs-after-move-mail-to-specific-folder](https://superuser.com/questions/929726/create-outlook-rule-which-runs-after-move-mail-to-specific-folder) to show a msgbox, but could not figure out how to get it to trigger when I moved a mail item to *any* folder in either my main email folder nor in the Archive.

Here is what I've tried:

(1) I added the following code to ThisOutlookSession (obviously with my actual email address):

```
Public WithEvents FolderItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set FolderItems = Session.Folders("Example@Email.Com").Folders("Misc").Items
End Sub

Private Sub FolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    MsgBox "ItemAdd event was triggered in folder Misc"
End Sub
```

That works *if* I move an email item into the "Misc" folder in my non-archived email account.  Yay.

But, I cannot figure out how to set the FolderItems object to trigger when an email is moved to *any* folder.

(2) I can reference the general Archive folder by using:

```
Set FolderItems = Session.Folders("Archives").Folders("Misc").Items
```

But, that only triggers if I move something to the specific "Misc" folder in Archives and I want to trigger the event when an email is moved to *any* Archive folder, not just the "Misc" folder.

I've tried

```
Set FolderItems = Session.Folders("Archives").Items
```

but that does not work--there's no error, it just does not trigger when I move an email into any folder, nor does it trigger when a new folder is added/created in Archives; so, I'm not sure what will trigger with that code.

Thanks for any pointers to get things further along!

Comment: Edit the question to include the code you used and indicate which module(s) you put it.

Comment: Frequently asked question apparently not possible, at least unanswered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100118/how-can-i-forward-email-i-move-to-non-specific-subfolders-of-a-specific-parent-f and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821714/add-folders-to-single-instance-of-itemadd-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @niton--apparently what I needed was for someone to tell me it was not possible!  ;)

The code below will provide an alert whenever a file is moved to an Archive folder.  (It will also provide an alert when any other change occurs too, so, it could get a little annoying for folks who are often messing with the Archive folders intentionally instead of unintentionally.)

I added the following code to the ThisOutlookSession Module and restarted Outlook and it works like a charm for me:

```
Public WithEvents myFolders As Outlook.Folders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolders = myNS.Folders("Archives").Folders
End Sub

Private Sub myFolders_FolderChange(ByVal Folder As Outlook.Folder)
    'this triggers when a change occurs in the Archives folder (e.g., a new item is moved into or deleted from some folder in the Archive folder [often inadvertently])
    MsgBox "You have made a change in the Archives folder."
End Sub
```

In the final code I use, the msgbox will ask if I want to Undo the action.  If I answer [Yes] then I use a SendKeys ^z  (ctrl+z) to automate the undo, but **I would love it if someone could tell me how to execute the Undo command using VBA, e.g., Application.Undo or something like that.**  I could not figure that out.

Thanks to @niton for pointing me to [this post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100118/how-can-i-forward-email-i-move-to-non-specific-subfolders-of-a-specific-parent-f) which had a comment by @Ryan Wildry which led me to [this information on Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/folders-folderchange-event-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) describing how to use the FolderChange event along with some sample code which I modified to fit my needs.