# Run a Python script on receiving email in the inbox and all it's sub folders in Outlook

Tags: python, vba, outlook, incoming-mail

I have a VBA script in ThisOutlookSession I want to call a Python script when an email arrives in my inbox.

My inbox has rules to move emails from specific senders into sub folders. When an email comes in that has a rule applied, my Python script does not get called.

I have looked at some solutions but they all appear to be hard coded in that the sub folders are directly referenced. I want to use this setup in my organsiation where I will have many users and inboxes with differing sub folder structures, so I am looking for a less hard coded solution.

I also understand that it may not be best to use rules and instead implement their functionality directly into the VBA script. As I wish to expand this to many users whilst retaining their ability to create new rules, I cannot use this method as it will require too much work to maintain when users want new rules.

```vb
Private WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

Debug.Print "Application_Startup triggered " & Now()

End Sub


Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

Dim my_olMail As Outlook.MailItem

If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then

    Dim obj As Object
    Dim PythonExe As String
    Dim Script As String

    Set obj = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\python"""

    Script = Environ("userprofile") & "\Python-Scripts\Outlook-Sound-Lock-Screen\play-sound.py"
    Debug.Print "Script Path: " & Script

    obj.Run "cmd /c cd /d" & PythonExe & "&& " & "python" & " " & Script, 0, True
    
    Set my_olMail = item
        Debug.Print "Sender: "; my_olMail.SenderEmailAddress & " | Subject: " & my_olMail.Subject
    Set my_olMail = Nothing
    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881358/run-code-when-new-email-comes-to-any-subfolder-in-a-shared-mailbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Eugene Astafiev's advice to use the NewMailEx() event I have been able to trigger my python script upon receiving a new email in the inbox and it's sub folders. I also fixed the issue related to the initialisation of the olApp raised by Eugene Astafiev.

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Set olApp = Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Debug.Print "Application_Startup triggered " & Now()

End Sub

Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

    Dim obj As Object
    Dim PythonExe As String
    Dim Script As String

    Set obj = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\python"""

    Script = Environ("userprofile") & "\Python-Scripts\Outlook-Sound-Lock-Screen\play-sound.py"

    obj.Run "cmd /c cd /d" & PythonExe & "&& " & "python" & " " & Script, 0, True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the `ItemAdd` event which is fired for a single folder you need to use the `NewMailEx` event of the Outlook `Application` class which is fired once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID returned by the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the `Inbox` and before client rule processing occurs. That means the new email is processed by the event handler before an Outlook rule may transfer it to any other folder. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you'll always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.

Also you may consider setting up the `ItemAdd` event handler on every folder where you need to process added items.

---

I have also noticed the following piece of code which contains an issue:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Where the `olApp` object is not initialized correctly. Use the `Application` property available in Outlook VBA environment instead, not a namespace:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

Set olApp = Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I have my script working as expected now.